# What is the difference between an opinion and a philosophical opinion?

Tags: aesthetics

What is the difference between an opinion and a philosophical position? If there is more than one philosophical position that is not obliterated easily by sniff sniff logic, how can that be the case? How can there be more than one philosophical position (as in burning books)?

Comment: Can you give an example where someone has found the difference between "opinion" and "philosophical opinion" sufficient to warrant exploration?

Comment: Also, why is this question tagged aesthetics? What is "sniff sniff logic?" Why would one conclude there could be only one philosophical position?

Comment: If I could answer your question with sniff sniff logic then it would be an example of an answer to a question with sniff sniff logic. But the fact is that sniff sniff logic only applies to philosophical positions not arbitrary questions, say.

Comment: Hmm, hmm, hmm. How can a question be put on hold as opinion-based if there is no difference between a philosophical position and an opinion. Breaking it down somewhat. .... ..... Is that much clearer ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assert there is none.

And in fact, it is dubious whether there is such a thing as an isolated philosophical position.  The essence of philosophy is in navigating context, and outside of a framework of interpretation, any given philosophical position, to the degree it retains any meaning at all, really is just an opinion.

A collection of opinions become philosophical positions when they attempt to make up a philosophy: to find a common context of interpretation that can reasonably guide thinking or behavior.